Where are extensions stored in NetLogo 6.4
I am trying to locate where the extensions are stored in NetLogo 6.4 (since version 6). Specifically, I need to extract the Table extension to use it with OpenMole.
The OpenMole container runs in headless mode, and it requires that all the extensions I use are placed in the same directory as my model. Unfortunately, the extensions folder in my NetLogo installation is empty.
Where can I find the Table extension's JAR file or its source? Alternatively, is there a recommended way to bundle extensions for use with OpenMole?

I'm not familiar with OpenMole, so this may be incorrect but since table is pre-installed in NetLogo itself, do you need to additionally provide the extension as a standalone? I'm wondering if the OpenMole restriction is specific to 'add-in' extensions that are not a part of the NetLogo distribution. Again- haven't used OpenMole so you may have already tested this!

Yes, unfortunately, I don’t know how NetLogo is packaged in the OpenMole task, but you need to provide it with the .jar files.
When the model works in OpenMole, it’s like jumping to lightspeed in the Millennium Falcon afterward. But for now, I’m stuck at the spaceport.

I finally found it. The extensions are in a hidden folder within the extensions directory. For me, the table extension is in extension/.bundled/table/...
